# Why window name changes window size on creation?

Tags: c++, opencv, window

I create a window by using the OpenCV library, where I show images from a folder. (Images are changed by clicking the space bar).

In the window name, I want to show the count of images which were already shown, e.g. "10 out of 20 images".

The problem appears, when I click the space bar and the new window with another image is shown, then the size of the window is changed (sometimes the window moves to another place on screen). How I can make the size of the windows stable? I want that all windows, which are created every time when the new image is shown, will have the same size and position.

Below code which I use:

```cpp
fullWindowName = SmString(windowName) << " " << i <<  " Out of " << filePaths.size();
cv::namedWindow(cv::String(fullWindowName), WINDOW_NORMAL | WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
cv::imshow(cv::String(fullWindowName), srcDisp);
cv::setMouseCallback(cv::String(fullWindowName), on_Mouse, &srcDisp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need [`resizeWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga9e80e080f7ef33f897e415358aee7f7e) and [`moveWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga8d86b207f7211250dbe6e28f76307ffb) to achieve that.

Here's some sample code:

```cpp
#include <opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::vector<cv::Mat> images;
    /* Feed some images here ... */

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << i + 1 << " out of " << images.size() << " images";
        std::string windowName = ss.str();
        cv::namedWindow(windowName, cv::WINDOW_NORMAL | cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);
        cv::resizeWindow(windowName, width, height);
        cv::moveWindow(windowName, x, y);
        cv::imshow(windowName, images[i]);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `cv::WINDOW_KEEPRATIO` doesn't work for me, maybe due to the lack of the Qt backend, cf. the documentation:

> Qt backend supports additional flags:
>
> WINDOW_NORMAL or WINDOW_AUTOSIZE: WINDOW_NORMAL enables you to resize the window, whereas WINDOW_AUTOSIZE adjusts automatically the window size to fit the displayed image (see imshow ), and you cannot change the window size manually.
>
> WINDOW_FREERATIO or WINDOW_KEEPRATIO: WINDOW_FREERATIO adjusts the image with no respect to its ratio, whereas WINDOW_KEEPRATIO keeps the image ratio.
>
> WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL or WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED: WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL is the old way to draw the window without statusbar and toolbar, whereas WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED is a new enhanced GUI. By default, flags == WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED

Apart from that, the window size and position is constant for all shown images.